# App to modify settings by application

Tags: settings, screen

Is there an app available that would let me modify my phone settings by application? To be specific, there are certain apps where I don't want the default screen timeout to occur. I'm on Gingerbread.

Comment: "the default screen timeout", what would that be?

Comment: Apps are able to request a permission from the Android system that allows them to suppress the screen timeout (e.g. when reading books / watching films). You should contact the developer of the app in case and ask him/her to implement that feature.

Comment: @slhck - if you go into the phone Settings (not app-specific), under Display (most likely) you can set the default screen timeout - i.e. have it go dark after x minutes of inactivity. There are some apps (like ones that runners use to track routes) that don't register as active because the user isn't interacting, so they go dark after the standard period.

Comment: @Flow - thanks, but I don't think that's going to happen. I know I've read about apps that let you do this; I just can't remember what they are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). This is a free automation app like Tasker, and it has the ability to modify the screen timeout.

Create a new Event. Add the condition `OR (match any)`. Then add a condition for each `Active application` that you want to keep the screen active.

Click the back button, then add the Action to change the `Screen Timeout` to never.

You then have to create a second Event that does the opposite. You create the `OR (match any)` condition, but this time select `Active application` and change the Status option to `App stopped or in background`, and again do this for each app you did in the first event. Set the `Screen Timeout` action to whatever timeout value you want normally.